# R: Processing data within a loop

Tags: r, loops

Below, I run a loop using the sample data provided, appending necessary items to `geneexptest`, and processing it further within the loop. However, in building `dfs`, I wish for the endpoint of each run to be `data.frame(geneexptotal,...)`, as shown. The problem is, it seems to be stopping somehow at `geneexptestapp`, and outputting that instead into `dfs` each round. Please let me know how I might include the rest of the loop into the output.

```
gex <- data.frame("sample" =  c("BIX","HEF","TUR","ZOP","VAG","JUF","FED","MEQ","YIF","HRB","LOP","LIX","COT","DRP","KFC","TUY","DOG","KEX","RAV","UEH"), 
                  "TCGA-F4-6703-01" = runif(20, -1, 1),
                  "TCGA-DM-A28E-01" = runif(20, -1, 1),
                  "TCGA-AY-6197-01" = runif(20, -1, 1),
                  "TCGA-A6-5657-01" = runif(20, -1, 1))
colnames(gex) <- gsub("[.]", "_",colnames(gex))

listx <- c("TCGA_DM_A28E_01","TCGA_A6_5657_01")

mxy <- data.frame("TCGA-AD-6963-01" = runif(20, -1, 1),
                  "TCGA-AA-3663-11" = runif(20, -1, 1),
                  "TCGA-AD-6901-01" = runif(20, -1, 1),
                  "TCGA-AZ-2511-01" = runif(20, -1, 1),
                  "TCGA-A6-A567-01" = runif(20, -1, 1)) 

colnames(mxy) <- gsub("[.]", "_",colnames(mxy))

zScore <- function(x,y)((as.numeric(x) - as.numeric(rowMeans(y,na.rm=T)))/as.numeric(sd(y,na.rm=T)))

    dfs <- lapply(listx, function(colName) {
      do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(mxy)), function(i) {
        zvalues <- zScore(gex[i,colName], mxy[i,])
        geneexptest <- data.frame(gex$sample[i], zvalues, row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
        geneexptest$zvalues <- as.numeric(as.character(geneexptest$zvalues))
        is.na(geneexptest) <- sapply(geneexptest, is.infinite)
        geneexptestapp <- na.omit(geneexptest)
        geneexptestorder <- geneexptestapp[order(geneexptestapp$zvalues, decreasing = FALSE, na.last = NA), ]
        geneexpa <- geneexptestorder[1:((0.05)*nrow(geneexptest)),]
        geneexpz <- geneexptestorder[(nrow(geneexptestorder)-((0.05)*nrow(geneexptest))):nrow(geneexptestorder),]
        geneexptotal <- rbind(geneexpa, geneexpz)
        data.frame(geneexptotal$gex.sample, row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
      }))
    })
```

Comment: Can you post what you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, as it is, is working fine.  You just have unexpected output because of some data management you're doing.  I broke your code out a bit to help with readability.  I made two new functions, fun1 and fun2 - fun2 is your inner function and fun1 is the outer function.  fun2 takes colName as an argument to pass it along.

```
fun2 = function(i,colName) {
  zvalues <- zScore(gex[i,colName], mxy[i,])
  geneexptest <- data.frame(gex$sample[i], zvalues, row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  geneexptest$zvalues <- as.numeric(as.character(geneexptest$zvalues))
  is.na(geneexptest) <- sapply(geneexptest, is.infinite)
  geneexptestapp <- na.omit(geneexptest)
  geneexptestorder <- geneexptestapp[order(geneexptestapp$zvalues, decreasing = FALSE, na.last = NA), ]
  geneexpa <- geneexptestorder[1:((0.05)*nrow(geneexptest)),]
  geneexpz <- geneexptestorder[(nrow(geneexptestorder)-((0.05)*nrow(geneexptest))):nrow(geneexptestorder),]
  geneexptotal <- rbind(geneexpa, geneexpz)
  data.frame(geneexptotal, row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
}

fun1 = function(colName) {
  do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(mxy)), fun2, colName=colName))
}

dfs <- lapply(listx, fun1)
```

So, listx has two column names in it - let's start with the first one, `TCGA_DM_A28E_01`.  So, we call `fun1("TCGA_DM_A28E_01")`.  This is going to `rbind` each of 5 (`nrow(mxy) = 5`) iterations for fun2.

So, let's start with `i=1` (we're now in fun2).  You take one value from `gex` and one row from `mxy`, put them in zScore which gives a value of -0.6955057.  You then make a one row data.frame and do some stuff to the zvalues column.  So we have:

```
> geneexptest
  gex.sample.i.    zvalues
1           BIX -0.6955057
```

Do some checks and verify that nothing is infinite and remove it if it is.  So now we have:

```
> geneexptestapp
  gex.sample.i.    zvalues
1           BIX -0.6955057
```

Now you do some ordering on a 1 row data frame.  Nothing changes.  This is where the problem is `nrow(geneexptest) = 1` so for `geneexpa` you're asking for rows `1:.05` which is the same as `1` and for `geneexpz` you're asking for rows `.95:1` which is `0.95`.  There are no fractional rows.  This results in:

```
> geneexpa;geneexpz
  gex.sample.i.    zvalues
1           BIX -0.6955057
[1] gex.sample.i. zvalues      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

which you `rbind` and return as a data frame.  In this case, it results in a single row data frame.  fun1 produces 5 of these and rbinds them together giving you a 5 row data.frame.  dfs is a list of 2 of these.

Your code suggests you expect to get more than 1 row (your multiplication suggests at least 20) but there's only 1.  Either the example here isn't complete or you need to rethink what's happening in fun2.

**UPDATE**

OK, given your updated requirements, consider this function:

```
getExtremeValues = function(x,p=0.05){
  z = x[,2]
  n = ceiling(nrow(x)*p)
  r = x[order(z),1]
  return(as.character(r[c(1:n,length(r):(length(r)-n+1))]))
}
```

You pass this function a dataframe (x), tell it which column has your zvalues (c = 2, by default) and what proportion you want from the top and bottom (p = 0.05 by default).  It then returns the first column where the zvalues are in the top and bottom percent.

How to make this all work:

```
fun2 = function(i,colName) {
  zvalues <- zScore(gex[i,colName], mxy[i,])
  geneexptest <- data.frame(gex$sample[i], zvalues, row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  geneexptest$zvalues <- as.numeric(as.character(geneexptest$zvalues))
  is.na(geneexptest) <- sapply(geneexptest, is.infinite)
  return(na.omit(geneexptest))
}

fun1 = function(colName) {
  getExtremeValues(do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(mxy)), fun2, colName=colName)))
}

dfs <- lapply(listx, fun1)
```

This returns:

```
> dfs
[[1]]
[1] "BIX" "TUY"

[[2]]
[1] "BIX" "TUR"
```

Given there are 20 samples, 1 is in the top 5%, 1 is in the bottom 5%, there are two column names listed in listx, so 4 samples returned.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I updated the OP to lengthen the sample data. Hope that helps.

Comment: the aim here is to extract the "sample" terms corresponding to the top and bottom 5% "zvalues". I hope that makes sense.

Comment: in fun2, I am trying to make `geneexpa` and `geneexpz` AFTER all rows have been bound together to geneexptest. I guess that is the problem here.

Comment: Henri - are you trying to get the extreme 5% zvalues from the samples (e.g., BIX, HEF, ...)?

Comment: I updated the OP.. in the last line, I am trying to extract `geneexptotal$gex.sample`, not just `geneexptotal`. So, for the first column name, I want to extract top and bottom 5% (most negative and most positive) `zvalues` out of the total (in this case, that means 8 values), and finally extract only the corresponding `sample` names for those 8 rows. Then, move on to the next column name. So, in the end in dfs I want two lists of samples, the first corresponding to `TCGA_DM_A28E_01` and the second corresponding to `TCGA_A6_5657_01`. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Just what I needed - however, as in the original version, I was wondering if it were possible get the top x and bottom x values, x being 5% of the original number of rows, NOT the number of rows after eliminating NAs and infinites. Thanks for this last request.

Comment: Fixed the getExtremeValues function.  Now it gets the ceiling of p*nrow(x) for the n rows from the top and bottom to return.  This could also be changed to floor() if you want.  It will always return at least one.